# Converting node grand_master_cas for Meteor

Tags: meteor, cas

I want to integrate CAS in Meteor, so any one please help me out to convert node grand_master_cas for Meteor CAS integration.

Comment: what is grand_master_cas?

Comment: It is a npm package for CAS integration with node.js                           url:https://www.npmjs.org/package/grand_master_cas